# WSO2 APIM: PKIX path building failed while configuring an endpoint with self signed certificate

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am getting the following error while trying to add an endpoint which uses self-signed ceritificate. Please find the image below

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVl27.png)

[2017-07-11 11:09:52,227] ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error occurred while connecting to backend : https://mytestserver.com, reason : sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.ce
rtpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.c
ertpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Can you please let me know how to fix this issue ?
So far I have tried the following 
1. adding -Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll property
2. Created a new keystore and added the self-signed certificate. Also added self-signed certificate to the java keystore

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the public certificate of this host, and install it to APIM's `client-truststore.jks` file.

```
keytool ­importcert ­alias MyCompany ­keystore client-truststore.jks ­­file MyCompany.crt
```